# mongoose getting `TypeError: user.save is not a function`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

When trying to post user data to database with mongoose, so the problem is like this:

In order for user to get credits i'm charging him "money" with stripe library so when im trying to post data into database im getting this error- TypeError: req.user.save is not a function

Here's the code:
//User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    googleId: String,
    credits: { type: Number, default: 0}
});

mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

//Route code 
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const stripe = require('stripe')(keys.stripeSecretKey);
const User   = require('../models/User');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/stripe',  async (req, res) => {
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 500,
      currency: 'usd',
      description: '$5 for 5 credits',
      source: req.body.id
    });
    req.user.credits += 5;
    const user = await req.user.save();

    res.send(user);
  });
};

//Index file
const express       = require('express');
const mongoose      = require('mongoose');
const keys          = require('./config/keys');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const passport      = require('passport');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');


mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);
const app  = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/billingRoutes')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
console.log('The server is running!');
```

Comment: Where are you setting `req.user`?

Comment: Doesn't passport do that for you after you log in? passport.initilizae and passport.session

Comment: I haven't used it too much before, but I don't think it does this automatically for you. Look at the docs [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) it seems that you need to set up your own functions in order to create the `req.user` object

Comment: can you share your passport.js file where serializeUser and deserializeUser function are located, because thats where deserializeUser() will set your req.user object

Answer (score 0):

.save() it's a method that should be used over the MongoDB object.

First you should find your user in your MongoDB, like for example:

```js
(async()=>{
 try{
  const user = await User.findById(userID)
  // now user is an Object which has the .save() method 

  // now you can modify the name of the userm for example
  user.name = "new name"

 // after saving the changes wit .save() method
 await user.save() // you're connecting with DB to communicate about introducing new data

 // ...
 }catch(err){
 // ...
 }
})()
```

Hope is useful.

Comment: Bit old, but what could be the reason of getting this error when doing it on a document returned by a `findOne` operation?